# Form request no funciona despues de cierta cantidad de reglas

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un Form Request con el que debo hacer algunas validaciones. Son en total 17 validaciones, pero no se porque solo esta funcionando con 6 de ellas, si agrego otra mas no me permite ver los errores.

Mi form request se llama RegistroRequest y tiene estas reglas:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_name' => 'required',
        'user_email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'nombre_cliente' => 'required',
        'direccion' => 'required',
        'persona_contacto' => 'required',
        // 'clave_oficina_virtual' => 'required',
        // 'clave_tss' => 'required',
        // 'clave_sirla' => 'required',
        // 'num_documento' => 'required',
        // 'telefono1' => 'required',
        // 'telefono2' => 'required',
        // 'correo1' => 'required',
        // 'cedula_tss' => 'required',
        // 'anexo2' => 'required',
        // 'anexo1' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Los mensajes de las validaciones los muestro en la vista con el siguiente codigo:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    <h5><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Hay un error con algun campo:</h5>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

@endif

Hasta este punto los mensajes de la validación se muestran bien, pero si descomento por ejemplo la regla para el campo 'clave_oficina_virtual', los mensajes ya no se muestran.

Este es mi request enviado:

```
{
    "_token": "MCuyhAVzJDoXbTayPIHCoKsZ38rsQiOKwwc8JJ9w",
    "user_name": null,
    "user_email": null,
    "password": null,
    "password_confirmation": null,
    "planes": [
    "9"
    ],
    "nombre_cliente": null,
    "actividad": "Financiera",
    "direccion": null,
    "persona_contacto": null,
    "clave_oficina_virtual": null,
    "clave_tss": null,
    "clave_sirla": null,
    "num_documento": null,
    "telefono1": null,
    "telefono2": null,
    "correo1": null,
    "cedula_tss": null,
    "anexo2": null,
    "anexo1": null,
    "metodo_pago": [
    "transferencia_deposito"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Si tienes el `input` con ese `id`?

Comment: Como debug te diría que descomentes todo, y en la vista hagas un `{{dump($errors->all())}}` a ver que te muestra

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ cuando hago eso solo se recarga la pagina pero no me muestra los mensajes del form request. Y si dejo las demás reglas comentadas entonces si e muestran los mensajes de esas.

Comment: @Bicho Si, lo he comprobado.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ me muestra un array vacio

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que la validación falla?¿Estás enviando el form con los inputs vacíos o como lo estás probando? Por lo que comentas, no hay errores de validación en la sesión. Otro debug sería poner `Log::debug($this->all());` en la función rules del FormRequest justo antes del return, luego revisa los logs de laravel  para ver que está llegando en el request.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127766/discussion-between-bpolanco-and-porloscerros-).